# Como pegar o valor do ID do usuário no CGridView - Yii

Tags: php, yii

No lugar de `{{ VALOR DO ID }}` eu gostaria de colocar o `ID` do respectivo usuário. Vendo que isso é uma `Row` de uma `Grid`.

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'usuario-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        'idUsuario',
        'nome',
        'email',
        array(
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
            'template'=>'{view}{update}{delete}',
            'buttons'=>array (
                'view' => array (
                    'options'=> array (
                            'data-url' => Yii::app()->controller->createUrl("view", array("id" => {{ VALOR DO ID }} )),
                    ),
                    'click'=>'function(){
                                   $(".content").load($(this).data("url"));
                              }',
                    'url'=>'"#"',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
)); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Contornei a situação dessa forma. Porém, não considero respondida a pergunta.

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'usuario-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        'idUsuario',
        'nome',
        'email',
        array(
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
            'template'=>'{view}{update}{delete}',
            'buttons'=>array (
                'view' => array (
                    'click'=>'function(e){
                                   e.preventDefault();
                                   $(".content").load($(this).attr("href"));
                              }',
                    'url'=>'Yii::app()->controller->createUrl("myAction",array("id"=>$data->primaryKey))'
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
)); ?>
```

Comment: Se você tem o PHP 5.3, você pode utilizar uma função da seguinte forma: 'url' => function($data) { return ...; }

Answer (score 0):

```
'url' => 'Yii::app()->controller->createUrl("view", array("id"=>$data->idUsuario))'
```

Answer (score -1):

Tente:

```
'data-url' => Yii::app()->controller->createUrl("view", array("id" => '$data->idUsuario' )),
```

Comment: tudo que eu coloco entre aspas ele considera como literal. Ou seja: <div data-url="$data->idUsuario"></div>. claro que os caracteres especiais são representados de outra forma, mas é basicamente isso que acontece.